# Highcharts 24 hour clock

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a chart that's displaying a flow of hashtags based on when they were posted. I want to have the x-axis display the time in an hourly fashion starting from 00:00 and with 1 hour in between display the entire cycle of 24 hours up to 23:00. Here's the problem, it only shows 00:00-22:00 and I can't for the life of me understand why. Here's the code:

```
    var Chart = (function () {
    function Chart() {
        var _this = this;
        this.data = { "TW": [174, 5, 278, 269, 282, 283, 271, 316, 251, 265, 273, 261, 265, 265, 45, 45, 60, 60, 46, 370, 428, 465, 404, 372], "IG": [266, 217, 221, 240, 220, 206, 193, 219, 186, 233, 213, 213, 243, 243, 109, 115, 128, 136, 196, 360, 483, 432, 382, 303], "GP": [31, 14, 13, 17, 14, 11, 8, 13, 12, 11, 20, 45, 22, 29, 17, 19, 27, 21, 18, 24, 37, 35, 20, 21], "total": 12009, "toptags": [{ "tag": "#paradisehotelSE", "count": 3600 }, { "tag": "#TV4", "count": 3240 }, { "tag": "#IdolSE", "count": 3126 }] };
        this.load(function () {
            _this.googleplus = _this.getData('googleplus');
            _this.twitter = _this.getData('twitter');
            _this.instagram = _this.getData('instagram');

            _this.init();
        });

Chart.prototype.init = function () {
        var hour = 3600 * 1000;

        $('#graph').highcharts({
            chart: {
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                type: 'spline',
                spacingBottom: 0,
                spacingTop: 0,
                spacingLeft: 1,
                spacingRight: 1,
                width: null,
                height: 270,
                animation: 2000
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    y: 12,
                    align: 'left',
                    style: {
                        color: 'white',
                        fontWeight: 'normal',
                        fontFamily: 'Open Sans'
                    }
                },
                showLastLabel: false,
                tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                tickWidth: 0,
                tickPixelInterval: 60,
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
                maxPadding: 0,
                minPadding: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                offset: 20,
                startOnTick: true,
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%H:%M'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                minorTickPosition: 'inside',
                gridLineColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)',
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    enabled: false,
                    text: 'Temperature'
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)',
                borderColor: 'none',
                shadow: false,
                style: {
                    color: 'white',
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    padding: '8px'
                },
                enabled: true,
                crosshairs: false,
                shared: false,
                snap: 30,
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.floor(this.y);
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                flags: {
                    shape: 'squarepin'
                },
                spline: {
                    dashStyle: 'ShortDot',
                    lineWidth: 4
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    pointStart: 0 * hour,
                    pointInterval: hour,
                    color: '#fda345',
                    name: 'Google plus',
                    marker: { enabled: false },
                    data: this.googleplus
                },
                {
                    pointStart: 0 * hour,
                    pointInterval: hour,
                    color: '#00aced',
                    name: 'Twitter',
                    marker: { enabled: false },
                    data: this.twitter
                },
                {
                    pointStart: 0 * hour,
                    pointInterval: hour,
                    color: '#f49ac1',
                    name: 'Instagram',
                    marker: { enabled: false },
                    data: this.instagram
                }]
        });
```

This is all the Javascript related to the chart, thanks a lot for looking into it.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing what your data looks like...

Comment: Sorry about that, added the data!

Answer (score 3):

You plot does indeed show data for 22:00 to 23:00.  The trouble is, though, that the 23:00 tick is getting suppressed.

Why?  Problem one, you've told highcharts to `startOnTick` but you haven't enabled the corresponding `endOnTick` [option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.endOnTick).  Problem two, your `maxPadding` option.  By setting it to 0 and having data that ends on 23:00, you've given Highcharts no space to add that last tick label.

```
//maxPadding: 0,
endOnTick: true
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0p69ra5/).

Comment: Is it possible to make the graph go all the way through to the end of the chart? It looks a bit abrupt when it ends in the middle of the chart. :)

Comment: @Daphen, I also missed you were setting the `showLastLabel` option to false.  This was suppressing the `23:00` label.  Taking that out: http://jsfiddle.net/e0p69ra5/2/.  You should really try and whittle those options down to the ones you really need.